# Convert amCHARTS to RTL

Tags: amcharts

[image]I am creating a Business Intelligence Application with AMCHARTS.  This application is supposed to be Multilingual. How can I convert a Graph made with AMCHARTS to rtl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no one-switch solution to amCharts which flips the whole chart.

If you need a true RTL chart, you would still need to set up your chart that way. I.e. putting value axis on the right (`valueAxes: [{ position: "right"}]`), etc.

Also, if your web page has RTL enabled, you will need to add this line of code **before** any other chart code:

```
AmCharts.rtl = true
```

---

To translate month names, use the [`AmCharts.shortMonthNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#shortMonthNames) and [`AmCharts.monthNames][2]` arrays.

I.e.:

```
AmCharts.shortMonthNames = [
  'يناير',
  'فبراير',
  'مارس',
  'إبريل',
  'مايو',
  'يونية',
  'يولية',
  'أغسطس',
  'سبتمبر',
  'أكتوبر',
  'نوفمبر',
  'ديسمبر'
];
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I am adding an image of the chart i need to modify (already implemented the valueAxes). Can you please advise what else I need to do on this chart to convert it to Arabic?

Comment: Did you mean to add the image to your question? Not seeiing it, I'm afraid.

Comment: sorry for that. Just added it now.

Comment: Updated my answer regarding month name translations. Not sure what else there needs to be done on the chart?

Comment: i added many custom codes to my amcharts from stack overflow or in another websites successfully  but today i added this amchart.rtl = true to my amcharts codes with different possible format to  my charts that those have diff format like  chart.rtl=true "rtl"=true; but it doesn't work.